# Flutter String Interpolation remain dolloar sign after compiled

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using code like below

```
get('/api/products/detail/$name/')
```

it seems working fine for most of cases as I expected like below

```
// If variable value is 'apple'
get('/api/products/detail/apple/')
```

but sometimes error are catched by sentry and sentry says

My request's url was **'/api/products/detail/$apple/'**

This happens not all the time and it makes me so unstable

Is there anybody why this is happening and how to prevent this?

I'm using flutter 2.8.1 and dart version 2.15.1

Comment: Are you sure you should not use $name and not $apple?

Comment: @Tizianoreica Yes my app is on appstore and playstore. And in most cases and test code, they works fine.

Comment: @Tizianoreica I found out on our mobile website's deeplink contains dollar sign. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: refer [string-interpolation](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-string-interpolation-in-dart)

```
var fruitName = "apple";
var apiURL = "/api/products/detail/$fruitName/";
print(apiURL);
```

your URL- `/api/products/detail/apple/`